# Rails aborted while making a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was trying to make a new rails project but at some point console showed that "rails aborted! TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Command". Of course I installed all the mandatory programs such as : SQLite3, Node.js or Yarn. Here's everything from console :

```
 rails new Webpage
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Zainicjowano puste repozytorium Gita w /home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/spring
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
      create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.6
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /usr/local/bin
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/build_info
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/cache
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/doc
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/specifications
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using activesupport 6.1.4.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using mini_portile2 2.6.1
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.12.3 (x86_64-linux)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.12.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.1
Using actionview 6.1.4.1
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.1.4.1
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using actioncable 6.1.4.1
Using globalid 0.5.2
Using activejob 6.1.4.1
Using activemodel 6.1.4.1
Using activerecord 6.1.4.1
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using mini_mime 1.1.0
Using activestorage 6.1.4.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
Using actionmailer 6.1.4.1
Using actiontext 6.1.4.1
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using bootsnap 1.7.7
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 2.1.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.35.3
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.15.3
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.0
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.7.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using puma 5.4.0
Using rack-mini-profiler 2.3.2
Using rack-proxy 0.7.0
Using thor 1.1.0
Using railties 6.1.4.1
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 6.1.4.1
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using semantic_range 3.0.0
Using spring 2.1.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using web-console 4.1.0
Using webdrivers 4.6.1
Using webpacker 5.4.2
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
       rails  webpacker:install
rails aborted!
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Command
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:2:in `<class:Thor>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:1:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/base.rb:1:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/group.rb:1:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:6:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/app_updater.rb:3:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:40:in `block in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:3:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:78:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:78:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:17:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:17:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:529:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `load_tasks'
/home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/Rakefile:6:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/home/wupeq/Dokumenty/Programowanie/WiekszeProjekty/Webpage/Webpage/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is wrong here? Should I install something? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: You most likely have both an older version of the thor gem loaded at the same time as 1.10. Seems to be a common issue on Debian. https://github.com/rails/thor/issues/721

Comment: @Mahys116 I'm using the newest version of Linux Mint